# Seams in shadows between adjacent divs

Tags: html, css, z-index, box-shadow

Adjacent elements typically appear as if they were fused, with no lines or seams between them). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4m3L79w4/1/

However, this does no longer appear to be the case if shadows are in use.

Html:

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Css:

```
DIV {
    background-color: #7faf7f;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px #000000;
}
.top {
    z-index: 2;
}
.bottom {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The "bottom" element projects shadow over the "top" one, even though both have the same z-index.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b4fvb7e0/1/

Is it possible to make the shadow between the two elements disappear, so that the look fused?

This is actually a simplified version of a header I am trying to create, which in some pages should appear fused to the next element. JSFiddle with the header standalone and with the following element: http://jsfiddle.net/c8oat7vo/3/

Comment: Not using the **same** box-shadow settings. You could probably manage something close with different settings on each.

Comment: `z-index` values within each "stack" need to be unique. Any elements that have the same value will be treated, relative to each other, in the same way they would without the `z-index` property, with the ones appearing later in the HTML structure being layered on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a pseudo element on top and bottom, and in this one set the shadow.

Also, set z-index of the pseudo elements to -1

fixed z-index issue thank to Jose Gomez

```css
DIV {
    background-color: #7faf7f;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.stack {
    background-color: #7f7faf;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 20%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px #000000;
    z-index: 1;
}
.top {
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.bottom {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: auto;
}

.top:after, .bottom:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 5px #000000;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="stack"></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Great hint! With z-index being -1, the shadow of bottom's pseudo-element is below the top element. However, the shadow of the stack element is still cut by the bottom element (stack does not lay shadow over bottom). Which can be fixed by changing the z-index of the stack element: http://jsfiddle.net/c8oat7vo/4/

Comment: Right, didn't notice the stack shadow issue. Corrected !